# Meteor different between initial data load and subsequent adds

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have an application that loads 50 chapters at once. While the chapters are being viewed, I want the application to play a sound when a new chapter's been loaded. This is how I think it's supposed to be done

```
Chapters.find().observe({
  added: function (user) {
    playSound()
  }
});
```

However this spams the sound on initial load, not just subsequent new chapters. How do I get it to only sound off on new chapters?

Edit: Looking for a Meteor answer, rather than, setTimeout or something. Though I'll do that if I have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wait for the first complete load of chapters before adding the `observe` callbacks.

```
Meteor.subscribe("chapters", someParam, function(){
    Chapters.find().observe({
      added: function (user) {
        playSound()
      }
    }); 
});
```

Of course you should add the observer only once, not every time the subscribe-callback fires.

Comment: Don't think this works. The callback fires before the chapters are added. So sound still plays.

Comment: This answer will work in combination with this: https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#why-does-observe-fire-a-bunch-of-added-events-for-existing-documents